# Multiple UILabel not displaying with UIView loaded from nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

I am trying to load a `UIView` from nib and place it as the 'header' for a `UICollectionView` using the following code inside the view controller's `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(220, 0, 0, 0);
self.overView = (OverviewView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverviewNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.overView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, -210, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, 200)];
[self.collectionView addSubview:self.overView];
```

The subview of class `OverviewView` has several `UILabel` in its nib with auto layout directives. One is to pin to the upper left hand corner of the view. But none of the `UILabel` show up.

I can see that the nib is being loaded as its `awakeFromNib` method is being called. Additionally I can see the background color of the view that I set in Interface Builder. I have set the view's Owner to the view controller's class.

How can I ensure that these `UILabel` show up?

Comment: Why are you adding it directly as a subview? Why isn't it part of the layout or a sibling to the collection view?

Comment: It's not a sibling to the collection view because I want the view to scroll with the collection view. If you know of a better way to do that, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create this as the header view in your layout and then set the content offset / inset to have it initially scroll off screen if that's your aim. By making it part of the layout it will be correctly managed, whereas by adding it directly to the collection view you're hiding it and hoping the collection won't mess with it...